# How to clear the incorrect user input from the command line and set the commandline cursor to its initial position in C# Console?

Tags: c#, command-line, console, user-input

If there is an incorrect user input that was put into the commandline, for example I clear it by using

```
menu:
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if(!int.TryParse(answer, out val))
    {
      Console.Clear(); 
      goto menu;
    }
```

However, doing this clears all the console window, what I want to know is that if there is a way to only clear the unwanted/incorrect user input and leave the rest of the Command Line stay the same and uncleared.

Comment: Consider using a _loop_ instead of `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Console class has a method called [SetCursorPosition(left, top)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-7.0) that allows you to move the point for the next input in the place you like.

Using this method you can replace the wrong text with an empty string with the same length of the input and then reposition again the cursor to get a new input.

Like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 5);
    Console.Write("Hello:");
    while (true)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out int val))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("     Valid input. Exiting    ");
            break;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("     Invalid input. Try again");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(11, 5);
        string delete = new string(' ', input.Length);
        Console.Write(delete);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(11, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you put ```if(input=="") break;``` control??

Comment: It is just an example. That line serves to exit the loop and terminate the example.

Comment: Updated to follow your code example.

Answer (score 1):

This code is the generalized solution of my original code in my OP:

```
        int val;
        string answer;    
        var top = Console.CursorTop;
        var left = Console.CursorLeft;
     menu:
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(cevap, out val))
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', answer.Length));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
            goto menu;
        }
```

Using `while(true){}` loop, the code above becomes:

```
                top = Console.CursorTop;
                left = Console.CursorLeft;
                string answer1;
                while (true)
                {
                    answer1 = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (int.TryParse(answer1, out val))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', answer1.Length));
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
                }
```